# Degrees of freedom of a point mass sliding on a rigid curved wire without friction

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, conventions, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

I am very new to the subject and am going through [Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6946/sicm-html/book.html).

> One exercise asks to find the [degrees of freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28mechanics%29) of a number of systems, one of which is a point mass sliding on a rigid, curved wire without friction.

Since there is nothing to suggest that the wire is not contained within a plane, I came up with an answer of 3. Is this correct? Surely, the mass *is* constrained to move along the wire, but can that reduce the dimension of the configuration space in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The number of degrees of freedom can be defined as the MINIMUM number of independent coordinates that can specify the position of the system completely" (wikipedia)
In your case the number is ONE, because you only need to know the position of the particle along the curve. It doesn't matter if the curve is not a line, or even contained on a plane, because you know the shape of the wire is predetermined and with only one number (the position along the wire), you can recover the 3D position of the particle.